# .nextAll not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the block of code inside a post request. The JSON reply is stored in 'data'

```
var a=data.Data.overview;
var b=data.Data.extras;
//summary
var result='';
result+='<div class="extra-upper-block">';
result+='<h5 class="extra-head"><i class="'+b[0].icon+' extra-head-icons"></i> '+b[0].category+'<i class="fa fa-pencil edit-prof"></i></h5>';
result+='<div class="extra-sub-block">';
if(b[0][0].summary!=null)
result+='<p id="profile-summary" class="extra-sub-block-summary">'+b[0][0].summary+'</p>';
result+='</div>';
result+='</div><hr class="extra-upper-block-separator">';
$('#profile-extras').append(result);
```

This works fine. Now I want to click the `<p>` tag on clicking

```
<i class="'+b[0].icon+' extra-head-icons"></i>
```

These are the codes I tried

```
$('.edit-prof').nextAll('.extra-sub-block-summary:first').click();

$('.edit-prof').nextAll('p:first').click();

$('.edit-prof').nextAll('div > .extra-sub-block-summary:first').click();
```

Nothing works. Why is the p not getting selected? I am executing the script only after the dynamic content is loaded.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4pC3e/

Comment: should use delegates for that..

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Can u explain it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click",".extra-sub-block-summary:first",function(){

});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

**Edit**

|The way you getting the element was wrong. 
Try this code

```
$('.edit-prof').closest("h5").next(".extra-sub-block").find(".extra-sub-block-summary:first").click();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pC3e/5/)

Comment: I want to explicitly make a click event on the <p> tag on clicking the <i> tag. I dont want to make a direct click on the <p> tag

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: can you try this $('.edit-prof').nextAll('.extra-sub-block-summary:first').trigger("click");

Comment: `$(...).trigger("click");` and `$(...).click();` are equal **[jQuery: click](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click)**.